# Gradle: same project source but generated jar is different

Tags: java, gradle

I'm using Intellij to generate a JAR file of our project using gradle, another person in my team has checked out exactly the same branch of our project, and generated the JAR also using gradle. But the JAR generated is different from mine (and one works on tomcat, one does not work).

We checked together, we found that many things in our JARs are different (compiled classes).

I would like to know how this can happen? What could be the potential cause for this ? Is it related to our cached libraries or gradle version?

Comment: Same versions of JDK?

Comment: and same file structure of the jar?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's exactly same version of JDK. But both JAR are compiled with Java 8. And the two jars do not have same file structure, when I unzip two JARs, some files are missing in another JAR.

Comment: But the code source is exactly the same.